# Selenium 2 chrome driver fails with WebException inside HttpCommandExecutor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup an automated test environment using

```
- TestStack.Seleno v0.8.2  
- TestStack.BDDfy v4.0.0
- Selenium .NET WebDriver 2.43.0.0
- Chrome v38  
- ChromeDriver v2.9
```

While I am able to establish initial session hand shake between chrome driver and chrome browser, subsequent calls to actual web application via chrome driver are failing with timeout exceptions.

Here is the code to instantiate a SelenoHost object :

```
       var options = new ChromeOptions();

        Instance.Run(configure => configure
            .WithWebServer(new InternetWebServer(String.Format("http://{0}/portal", IISServerHost)))
            .WithRemoteWebDriver(() => BrowserFactory.Chrome(options))
            .UsingLoggerFactory(new ConsoleFactory()));
```

If I debug the above method call, it fails inside SelenoApplication Initialize method :

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _initialised = true;
        _logger.Debug("Starting Webserver");
        WebServer.Start();
        _logger.Debug("Browsing to base URL");
        Browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(WebServer.BaseUrl); >>> this line fails inside HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse() method
    }
```

Not able to figure out what obvious am i missing out here.

BTW, web application is hosted on IIS 7.5 and is configured for windows authentication.

Comment: What's the stack trace say?

Comment: System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The operation has timed out
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request) in c:\Downloads\selenium-2.43.0\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line 142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching chrome with 'no-sandbox' resolved the issue.

Here is how the final configuration looks like :

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");  
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");  

var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.EnableVerboseLogging = (ChromeDriverVerboseLogigng == "true");
driverService.LogPath = ChromeDriverLogPath;

_SelenoHostLazy.Value.Run(configure => configure
.WithWebServer(new InternetWebServer(String.Format("http://localhost/portal", IISServerHost)))
.WithRemoteWebDriver(() => new ChromeDriver(driverService, options))
.UsingLoggerFactory(new ConsoleFactory()));
```